# ERROR ID esp32_esp32internalgpiopin_6 is already registered - ESPHome component

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32, arduino-esp32, esphome

I'm trying to create a component for ESPHome.

I'm getting:
`ERROR ID esp32_esp32internalgpiopin_6 is already registered`

With this config:

```yaml
...
external_components:
  - source:
      type: git
      url: https://github.com/Defozo/esphome
      ref: dev
    components: [ tmc2130 ]
    refresh: 3s

spi:
  clk_pin: 18
  mosi_pin: 23
  miso_pin: 19

stepper:
  - platform: tmc2130
    id: my_stepper
    step_pin: 21
    dir_pin: 16
    cs_pin: 26
    r_sense: 0.11
    microsteps: 16
    rms_current: 1500
```

stepper.py

```py
import esphome.codegen as cg
import esphome.config_validation as cv
from esphome import pins
from esphome.components import spi
from esphome.const import CONF_ID, CONF_CS_PIN
from esphome.core import coroutine

DEPENDENCIES = ['spi']
AUTO_LOAD = ['sensor']

tmc2130_ns = cg.esphome_ns.namespace('tmc2130')
TMC2130Component = tmc2130_ns.class_('TMC2130Component', cg.Component, spi.SPIDevice)

CONF_TOFF = "toff"
CONF_BLANK_TIME = "blank_time"
CONF_RMS_CURRENT = "rms_current"
CONF_MICROSTEPS = "microsteps"
CONF_TCOOLTHRS = "tcoolthrs"
CONF_THIGH = "thigh"
CONF_SEMIN = "semin"
CONF_SEMAX = "semax"
CONF_SEDN = "sedn"
CONF_SGT = "sgt"
CONF_R_SENSE = "r_sense"
CONF_STEP_PIN = "step_pin"
CONF_DIR_PIN = "dir_pin"

CONFIG_SCHEMA = cv.Schema({
    cv.GenerateID(): cv.declare_id(TMC2130Component),
    cv.Required(CONF_CS_PIN): pins.gpio_output_pin_schema,
    cv.Required(CONF_STEP_PIN): pins.gpio_output_pin_schema,
    cv.Required(CONF_DIR_PIN): pins.gpio_output_pin_schema,
    cv.Required(CONF_RMS_CURRENT): cv.positive_int,
    cv.Required(CONF_R_SENSE): cv.float_,
    cv.Optional(CONF_TOFF, default=4): cv.int_range(min=0, max=15),
    cv.Optional(CONF_BLANK_TIME, default=24): cv.int_range(min=16, max=54),
    cv.Optional(CONF_RMS_CURRENT, default=1500): cv.positive_int,
    cv.Optional(CONF_MICROSTEPS, default=16): cv.int_range(min=0, max=256),
    cv.Optional(CONF_TCOOLTHRS, default=0xFFFFF): cv.hex_int,
    cv.Optional(CONF_THIGH, default=0): cv.hex_int,
    cv.Optional(CONF_SEMIN, default=5): cv.int_range(min=0, max=15),
    cv.Optional(CONF_SEMAX, default=2): cv.int_range(min=0, max=15),
    cv.Optional(CONF_SEDN, default=0b01): cv.int_range(min=0, max=0b11),
    cv.Optional(CONF_SGT, default=7): cv.int_range(min=-64, max=63),
}).extend(cv.COMPONENT_SCHEMA).extend(spi.spi_device_schema())

async def to_code(config):
    cs_pin = await cg.gpio_pin_expression(config[CONF_CS_PIN])
    step_pin = await cg.gpio_pin_expression(config[CONF_STEP_PIN])
    dir_pin = await cg.gpio_pin_expression(config[CONF_DIR_PIN])
    r_sense = config[CONF_R_SENSE]
    var = cg.new_Pvariable(config[CONF_ID], cs_pin, r_sense)
    await cg.register_component(var, config)
    await spi.register_spi_device(var, config)

    cg.add_library('TMCStepper', '0.7.3')
    cg.add(var.set_step_pin(step_pin))
    cg.add(var.set_dir_pin(dir_pin))
    cg.add(var.set_toff(config[CONF_TOFF]))
    cg.add(var.set_blank_time(config[CONF_BLANK_TIME]))
    cg.add(var.set_rms_current(config[CONF_RMS_CURRENT]))
    cg.add(var.set_microsteps(config[CONF_MICROSTEPS]))
    cg.add(var.set_tcoolthrs(config[CONF_TCOOLTHRS]))
    cg.add(var.set_thigh(config[CONF_THIGH]))
    cg.add(var.set_semin(config[CONF_SEMIN]))
    cg.add(var.set_semax(config[CONF_SEMAX]))
    cg.add(var.set_sedn(config[CONF_SEDN]))
    cg.add(var.set_sgt(config[CONF_SGT]))
```

tmc2130.cpp

```cpp
#include "tmc2130.h"
#include "esphome/core/log.h"
#include <TMCStepper.h>

namespace esphome {
namespace tmc2130 {

static const char *const TAG = "tmc2130";

TMC2130Component::TMC2130Component(uint8_t cs_pin, float r_sense)
  : driver_(cs_pin, r_sense) {}

void TMC2130Component::setup() {
  ESP_LOGD(TAG, "Setting up TMC2130...");
  pinMode(EN_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(STEP_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DIR_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(EN_PIN, LOW); // Enable driver by default

   this->driver_.begin(); // Initiate SPI
  // Configuration values are now set from the YAML file
  this->driver_.toff(this->toff_);
  this->driver_.blank_time(this->blank_time_);
  this->driver_.rms_current(this->rms_current_); // Set motor RMS current
  this->driver_.microsteps(this->microsteps_);
  this->driver_.TCOOLTHRS(this->tcoolthrs_);
  this->driver_.THIGH(this->thigh_);
  this->driver_.semin(this->semin_);
  this->driver_.semax(this->semax_);
  this->driver_.sedn(this->sedn_);
  this->driver_.sgt(this->sgt_);

  // Setup timer
  this->timer_ = timerBegin(0, 80, true); // Use the first timer
  timerAttachInterrupt(this->timer_, &onTimer, true); // Attach the interrupt function
  timerAlarmWrite(this->timer_, 1000, true); // Set the alarm
  timerAlarmEnable(this->timer_); // Enable the alarm
}

void TMC2130Component::set_toff(uint8_t toff) { this->toff_ = toff; }
void TMC2130Component::set_blank_time(uint8_t blank_time) { this->blank_time_ = blank_time; }
void TMC2130Component::set_rms_current(uint16_t rms_current) { this->rms_current_ = rms_current; }
void TMC2130Component::set_microsteps(int microsteps) { this->microsteps_ = microsteps; }
void TMC2130Component::set_tcoolthrs(uint32_t tcoolthrs) { this->tcoolthrs_ = tcoolthrs; }
void TMC2130Component::set_thigh(uint32_t thigh) { this->thigh_ = thigh; }
void TMC2130Component::set_semin(uint8_t semin) { this->semin_ = semin; }
void TMC2130Component::set_semax(uint8_t semax) { this->semax_ = semax; }
void TMC2130Component::set_sedn(uint8_t sedn) { this->sedn_ = sedn; }
void TMC2130Component::set_sgt(int8_t sgt) { this->sgt_ = sgt; }
void TMC2130Component::set_r_sense(float r_sense) { this->driver_.rsense(r_sense); }


void TMC2130Component::loop() {
  // This method can be used to update the component state in each loop iteration
  // For example, handling dynamic speed adjustments or other runtime tasks
}

void TMC2130Component::dump_config() {
  ESP_LOGCONFIG(TAG, "TMC2130 Component Configuration:");
  ESP_LOGCONFIG(TAG, "  - Toff: %u", this->toff_);
  ESP_LOGCONFIG(TAG, "  - Blank Time: %u", this->blank_time_);
  ESP_LOGCONFIG(TAG, "  - RMS Current: %u", this->rms_current_);
  ESP_LOGCONFIG(TAG, "  - Microsteps: %d", this->microsteps_);
  ESP_LOGCONFIG(TAG, "  - TCOOLTHRS: %u", this->tcoolthrs_);
  ESP_LOGCONFIG(TAG, "  - THIGH: %u", this->thigh_);
  ESP_LOGCONFIG(TAG, "  - SEMIN: %u", this->semin_);
  ESP_LOGCONFIG(TAG, "  - SEMAX: %u", this->semax_);
  ESP_LOGCONFIG(TAG, "  - SEDN: %u", this->sedn_);
  ESP_LOGCONFIG(TAG, "  - SGT: %d", this->sgt_);
}

void TMC2130Component::set_speed(int speed) {
  // Adjust timer alarm based on speed
  if (speed > MAX_SPEED && speed < MIN_SPEED) {
    uint32_t timer_speed = map(speed, 0, 100, MIN_SPEED, MAX_SPEED); // Map speed to timer range
    timerAlarmWrite(this->timer_, timer_speed, true);
  }
}

void TMC2130Component::set_direction_forward(bool forward) {
  motor_direction_ = forward;
  digitalWrite(DIR_PIN, motor_direction_ ? HIGH : LOW); // Set direction
}

void TMC2130Component::enable_motor(bool enable) {
  // Enable or disable motor by controlling EN_PIN
  digitalWrite(EN_PIN, !enable); // LOW to enable, HIGH to disable
}

static void IRAM_ATTR onTimer() {
  digitalWrite(STEP_PIN, !digitalRead(STEP_PIN)); // Toggle the step pin
}

}  // namespace tmc2130
}  // namespace esphome
```

tmc2130.h

```
#include "esphome/core/component.h"
#include "esphome/core/hal.h"
#include <TMCStepper.h>

namespace esphome {
namespace tmc2130 {

class TMC2130Component : public Component {
 public:
  void setup() override;
  void dump_config() override;
  void set_toff(uint8_t toff);
  void set_blank_time(uint8_t blank_time);
  void set_rms_current(uint16_t rms_current);
  void set_microsteps(int microsteps);
  void set_tcoolthrs(uint32_t tcoolthrs);
  void set_thigh(uint32_t thigh);
  void set_semin(uint8_t semin);
  void set_semax(uint8_t semax);
  void set_sedn(uint8_t sedn);
  void set_sgt(int8_t sgt);
  void set_direction_forward(bool forward);
  void set_r_sense(float r_sense);

 protected:
  TMC2130Stepper driver_;
  uint8_t toff_;
  uint8_t blank_time_;
  uint16_t rms_current_;
  int microsteps_;
  uint32_t tcoolthrs_;
  uint32_t thigh_;
  uint8_t semin_;
  uint8_t semax_;
  uint8_t sedn_;
  int8_t sgt_;
  bool motor_direction_{true};
  float r_sense_;
};

}  // namespace tmc2130
}  // namespace esphome
```

I don't understand the error. Where am I defining this esp32_esp32internalgpiopin_6? Can someone help?

Comment: Almost all ESP32 pins have multiple uses.  GPIO6 is also the SPI clock and/or CTS for UART #1.  If you are using either of those components, then it can't be GPIO6.

Comment: I removed `await spi.register_spi_device(var, config)` and I don't see the error anymore... I wonder though whether this is the real solution?

Comment: Of course it is.  One of the pains of the ESP32s is how overloaded the pins are.  If you need SPI in the future, then you will have to move whatever you have on GPIO6 to some other pin.